# mysql --login-path connecting to the wrong database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a strange problem with mysql and the --login-path option.
I have configurated multiple users and databases, some local and some remote using mysql_config_editor.

But since I had my last configuration it seems mysql --login-path=any_config_entry is always connecting to the last entered configuration as if I entered mysql --login-path=last_config_entry.

What could it be?

version is:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 0):

OK so I think I found the problem, I recently added an entry, and looking at my bash history I can see that I entered the information with set two times once without the --login-path resulting in creating an entry with the name client

after removing this entry with : mysql_config_editor remove --login-path client
all other configuration paths are working again.